# Game 1 program Error (using string position 1 of name to age as a guessing game number)

Tags: c++

I am having some errors in this code.

I just want to make a certain function to work that I thought it would work.

Of course, because of this, the program is not running because of this errors...

(The code has comments on it, explaining what stuff do stuff.)

> Error (active)    E1345   an empty initializer is invalid for an array with unspecified bound
>
> Error   C2040   'name': 'std::string []' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::string'
>
> Error   C2466   cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Those errors are caused by this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
string name; //your name
string age; //your age
string pueblo; //Where you live

//The rest is using "getline(cin, those strings)" for each one.

//Until... this part...

srand(time(NULL)); //Just activating the random seed
        int i = 0;
        string name[] = {};
        string hr;
        int n = rand() % 1;
        hr = name[n]; //this part is nonsensical

        int Game1Attempt = 0; //The tries

        cout << "Juego 1\n";
        cout << "Tienes 3 oportunidades para adivinar el numero. El numero esta entre " << name[1] << " y tu edad mas las letras de tu nombre.\n";
/*Translation:
Game 1:
You have 3 tries to figure the number out. 
The number is between the "Position 1 of your string name" and your "string age" plus the letters of your string name*/

        while (Game1Attempt < 3) //Self-Explainatory
        {
            /*Here I'm trying to get the user input to guess what position
    Of those strings, is the number you are trying to figure out for example
      Your Name[1] and Age 10 + Letters of Your Name*/
            cout << "Intento 1:";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "\nIntento 2:";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "\nIntento 3:";
            cin >> n;
        }
        if (Game1Attempt == 3)
            cout << "The number was " << n << endl; 
           //Lastly if user tried 3 times, ends with revealing what number was so... (Position 1 from Name to Age plus Letters of Name) I still don't get it...
```

All I want is to resolve this error. But I am doing it incorrectly. Any tips?

Comment: You got 2 definitions of `name`: `string name;` and `string name[] = {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do

```
string name;
```

That defines the variable `name` as a `string` object, and default constructs it.

Then you do

```
string name[] = {};
```

This attempts to ***re-define*** the variable `name`, as an *array* of unknown size. This is not allowed, an array must have a size. And it looks like you don't really want `name` to be an array, but a single `string` object. So just delete that re-definition line.

If you *do* want to have an array of `string` objects, then you need to give it a size. Or better yet use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a dynamically sized "array". Oh and you should not name it the same as another variable in the same scope.